# Ionic not hiding pages

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an ionic + angular app. When I try to move from the homescreen by clicking the "sign up with mobile number" button , the home page still shows and the form does not render completely.

Sign Up Form

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar class="tool">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Register</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="content">
  <form>
    <!-- <img class="logo" src="../../../assets/logo.png" width="70px" height="90px"/> -->
    <div id="recapture-container" ></div>
    <div *ngIf="!otpSent">
        <ion-input id="phoneNumber"  class="input" type="text" required [(ngModel)] = "phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber"></ion-input>
  <ion-col align-self-center>
      <ion-button (click)="sendOTP()">
        <span class="button-text">Sign In</span>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-col>
    </div>
   
    <div *ngIf="otpSent">
      <ion-note>
        Please enter the OTP sent to {{phoneNumber}}
      </ion-note>
        <ion-input id="otp" class="input"></ion-input>
      <ion-button (click)="verifyOTP()">
        <span class="button-text"> Verify</span>
      </ion-button>
    </div>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

Home

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic 4 Form
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="auth-form">
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col align-self-center>
        <ion-button [routerLink]="['/register-page']" expand="block" color="primary">
          <ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon>Register with Email</ion-button>
         <span class="divider line one-line">or</span>
        <ion-button [routerLink]="['/register-mobile-page']" expand="block" color="primary">
          <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>Sign In With Mobile Number</ion-button>

        <span class="divider line one-line">or</span>

        <span class="already">Already a user?</span>

        <ion-button [routerLink]="['/login']" expand="block" color="danger">Sign In</ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

CSS

```
.content {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .logo {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 125px;
  }

  ion-title {
    color: #000000;
  }

  .logo {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 125px;
  }
  
  .input {
    @include input-styles
  }

  .has-focus {
    border: 1px solid $color-primary;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 $color-primary;
  }
  
.tool,
.content {
  --background: #ffffff;
}

ion-button {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 105px;
    --background: #e0a448;
    --border: 1px solid #e0a448;
    --border-radius: 20.5px;
    height: 39px !important;
    width: 142px !important;
    &:active {
      --box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 #e0a448!important;
      &:hover {
        --background: #e19a2f!important;
      }
    }
  }

.button-text{
  font-family: "BentonSans-Medium" !important;
  font-size: 13px !important;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: none;
}
```

I have attached a screenshot of the issue. I see the "page-is-hidden" class is missing from in my console but I don't know how to fix this[image]

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @cjd82187 no errors